# Python change the element in sublists according to a dict then sum the new list togther

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to change the element which is a int in a group of sublist according to a dictionary, then sum the values in new sublists together. For example:

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[0]]
dict = {0: 6, 1: 6, 2: 2, 3: 13, 4: 12, 5: 11, 6: 10}
```

So after changing, it will be:

```
changed_list = [[6,2,13],[12,11],[10],[6]]
```

then sum the elements in sublists

```
new_list = [21,23,10,6]
```

So how to do this in a general way?

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this...

Comment: OK, but that isn't really a question. Break it down into smaller problems, then solve each one. I'd recommend reading up on *"list comprehensions"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

```
list_ = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [0]]
dict_ = {0: 6, 1: 6, 2: 2, 3: 13, 4: 12, 5: 11, 6: 10}
```

*Note the underscores. Do not overwrite the python built-ins!*

There is the ninja way:

```
final_list = [sum(f) for f in [[dict_.get(x, x) for x in sublist] for sublist in list_]]
```

or more elegantly but still as ninja: (kudos @Chris_Rands)

```
final_list = [sum(dict_.get(x, x) for x in sublist) for sublist in list_]
```

and the much more verbose version of it:

```
final_list = []
for sublist in list_:
    acc = 0
    for item in sublist:
        acc += dict_.get(item, item)
    final_list.append(acc)
```

Both code snippets do the same thing of course and produce `[21, 23, 10, 6]`.

This is definitely code you could have written yourself with some (or not as much) effort. The only thing that is noticeable is the use of the `.get()` dictionary method since I wouldn't like to get an index error if one of the list elements does not exist as `key` in the dictionary `dict_`.

Comment: Counter-ninja: `[sum(d[it_elt] if it_elt in d else it_elt for it_elt in it_list) for it_list in l]`

Comment: @Rightleg There are many **ninja factions**. Thankfully. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using map and sum:

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[0]]
dict = {0: 6, 1: 6, 2: 2, 3: 13, 4: 12, 5: 11, 6: 10}

new_list = map(sum, [[dict[b] for b in i] for i in list]) #for Python 2

new_list = list(map(sum, [[dict[b] for b in i] for i in list])) #for Python 3
```

Comment: +1 for using `map` and expanding the diversity of solutions, but list comprehension can usually do the same as `map` but in a more readable way.

Comment: And to make the solution Python-version ignorant, you have to cast `map` to `list`.

Comment: `[sum(dict[i] for i in l) for l in list]`

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension :

```
[sum([dict[x] for x in y]) for y in list]
```

Output :

```
[21, 23, 10, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using list comprehension and sum:

```
list_initial = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[0]]

dict_inicial = {0: 6, 1: 6, 2: 2, 3: 13, 4: 12, 5: 11, 6: 10}

changed_list = [[element if element == dict_inicial[element]
                         else dict_inicial[element] for element in sublist] for sublist in list_initial]
new_list = [sum(sublist) for sublist in changed_list]
```

`